# Do I need to create thread safe variable?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Do I need to create thread safe variable? I will use mydata only in the mainThread and  the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue().

```
-(void) mainThread
{
 mydata = 55;
}

-(void) concurrentThread
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
 {
  mydata = 77;                          
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to do anything special to `mydata` in this case, since it is only ever updated from the main thread (assuming that `mainThread` means that method is only ever called from the main thread). This also assumes you are not trying to read `mydata` from anywhere but the main thread as well.

**Further explanation:**

Even though concurrentThread is running on a thread other than the main thread, the fact that `mydata = 77` appears in a block that is dispatched to the main thread means that the assignment will actually take place on the main thread, in some serial order along with any other read/write to that variable that occurs on the main thread. So assuming there isn't some code anywhere else not on the main thread that accesses mydata, this code is safe.

Comment: Which doesn't protect any other thread to **read** garbage when it tries to read while the mainthread is updating the variable.

Comment: I don't see any code here that does anything to the `mydata` variable outside of the main thread. If you are making assumptions about whether he is reading the variable from elsewhere, then that is a different story.

Comment: It's a piece of code running on another thread (i.e. not the main thread). However, the assignment to mydata that appears in concurrentThread is actually taking place on the main thread.

Comment: I see, the dispatch makes both assignments happen on the main thread.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Yup. It's a fairly common pattern, particularly when you need to update the UI from a thread other than the main thread.